# Customise default site setup

Tags: customization

Can anyone point me in the direction of the codex or function that controls the default setup of a site within a multisite network.  Basically I don't want to have to be deleting all the widgets, sample page and post every time I create a new site - which will be a lot on the site network I'm building.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

One way to go is to use the plugin [Multisite Clone Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/)

Multisite function is explained in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#Multisite_functions).